# How do I sketch the following planar phase system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am asked to sketch the phase portrait of this system? $$\begin{cases}x'=4x-2y\\ y'=2x-6y+1\end{cases}$$

I would know how to do it if I had $$\begin{cases}x'=4x-2y\\ y'=2x-6y\end{cases}$$

How does this $+1$ affect the phase portrait?

Comment: Well, how would you sketch the phase portrait for the second system without the $+1$?

Comment: @CheeHan I would calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix. In this case the eigenvalues are both real: $-\sqrt(21)-1$ and  $\sqrt(21)-1$ Meaning I have a saddle in the equilibrium point $(0,0)$ And to see which edge is the stable and which the unstable I would just calculate the eigenvectors.

Comment: But if you haven't seen linear stability analysis on nonlinear system before, then there is another way that is only applicable to your system. Yes, your given system is nonlinear, but it is nonlinear in the special way that all we do is adding a constant to one of the derivatives; geometrically, this means that we are simply shifting the "linear system" by some constants, i.e. the given nonlinear system is actually linear is some other variables $(\tilde x,\tilde y)$, say.

Comment: To see this, set $\tilde x = x - a$ and $\tilde y = y - b$ for some real numbers $a$ and $b$. Note that $(\tilde x)' = x'$ and similarly $(\tilde y)' = y'$, so the left-hand side remains unchanged and we just need to find $a$ and $b$ such that $4\tilde x - 2\tilde y = 4x - 2y$ and $2\tilde x - 6\tilde y = 2x - 6y + 1$. This yields two linear equations in $a$ and $b$ which one can solve easily. The upshot is that, in this new coordinates $(\tilde x,\tilde y)$, your system now becomes $\tilde x' = 4\tilde x - 2\tilde y$, $\tilde y' = 4\tilde x - 2\tilde y$ and you can apply what you know before

Comment: @CheeHan All of that should’ve been an answer instead of a bunch of long comments. If what you have to say doesn’t fit into the character limit of a single comment, that’s generally a sign that you’re really writing an answer.

Comment: @amd Agree, but I wasn't sure if the OP knows about linearisation or not, hence my second and third comment (:

Comment: @Chee Han. The equations are still linear. But they are non-homogeneous.

Comment: @Chrystomath YESSS you are right! My bad.......